# Is it allowed to spawn processes from Android apps?

Tags: android

Is it allowed to execute another process from within an Android app like so:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dalvikvm ....");
```

I seem to be getting a security exception, however, I *can* execute "su" in this way.

Comment: It generally works at the moment, however all the details must be right.  You probably need to specify the path to the executable, also you may need a way to pass arguments.  Is there a reason you cannot have android run the code for you in a normal application process? (you can use specifiers in the manifest to have it run in a different application process, if for some obscure reason you need that)

Comment: I have to embed some legacy code that does a System.exit() on error. I could wrap it as a service, but even in a service System.exit() isn't desirable although it might work.

Comment: You really should fix that to have some other error handling.  But you can say in the manifest that a service runs in its own process - that way Android will take care of the details of starting it for you.  Otherwise, if you really want to figure out how to launch a VM yourself (which is trickier than just a random native executable), you can try looking at the source of the 'am' command for example - but beware that you may have a lot of difficulty using Android APIs if you do this.

Comment: The legacy stuff is not mine, there is no source and I'm not allowed to patch it. Will try the service route. thx.

Comment: Legacy java code?  If so how did you get it to android compatible smali?   Smali code is quite patchable since everything external still has its symbolic name - you could substitute your own static method which connects back to the rest of your code and forces a more recoverable shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to execute processes this way from the application'a data directory. For example, in this project they execute ffmpeg binary (which they first put from res/raw into the app's dir) https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java/tree/master/src/org/ffmpeg/android

I don't know about processes outside of the app dir.

Comment: The file needs to be marked executable and readable, and not be on a partition with the noexec mount flag.  An app's private directory is likely the only *portable* place where you can accomplish that on a recent secured device, but there have been other possible scratch directories on various builds.  Depending on the permission bits set by the owning app, other apps may be able to execute it as well.